# Akka Remoting: Unable to serialize actor

Tags: scala, akka, akka-remote-actor

## Setup

Using Akka ( 2.3.9 ) remoting.

I have a io.Tcp akka system which talks to another remote backend akka system.

Problem is the message sent back by the remote never gets to the tcp system.

Front ( Tcp ) system registers a 'follower' class when connection is received.

Follower identifies ( successfully ) the remote backend system, then forwards on the received data

Snippet from Follower:

```
def receive = {
    case ActorIdentity(`identifyId`, Some(ref)) =>
        log.error( "Identified successfully" )
        context.watch(ref)
        context.become(active(ref))
    case ActorIdentity(`identifyId`, None) =>
        log.error( "Failed to identify remote" )
        context.stop(self)
}

def active(another: ActorRef): Actor.Receive = {
    case Terminated(`another`) => context.stop(self)
    case data: Received =>
        log.debug( "Forwarding message" )
        another forward data
    case other : Any =>
        log.warning( "Unexpected case :" + other.getClass )
}
```

Remote system listens for Received case, then Writes reply to sender.

```
 override def receive =  ( {
    case Received( data ) =>
        sender() ! Write( processData( data ) )
    case _ => log.debug( "Unexpected receive" )

} : PartialFunction[Any, Unit] ) orElse super.receive
```

### Problem

Everything works, remote akka system correctly reads the received data, processes it but poos itself when writing back the result.

```
EndpointWriter - AssociationError [akka.tcp://front-tcp@127.0.0.1:2553] -> [akka.tcp://backend@127.0.0.1:2552]: Error [akka.io.Tcp$Write; unable to create instance]
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?

## UPDATE:

I pass an Ack back from the remote now ( in backend system )

```
case object Ack extends Event

 override def receive =  ( {
    case Received( data ) =>
        sender() ! Write( processData( data ), Ack )
```

Now I get told that the remote Actor (MyHandler in this log ) is not serializable:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: handler.MyHandler
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
```

Shouldn't MyHandler be automatically serializable since it's an actor?

### Update 2

I just Await the result of an 'ask' to the remote now:

```
def active(another: ActorRef): Actor.Receive = {
    case Terminated(`another`) => context.stop(self)
    case Received( message ) =>
        val futRemoteAnswer = ask( another, message ).mapTo[ Message ]
        val result = Await.result( futRemoteAnswer, timeout.duration )
        sender() ! Write( result )
    case other : Any =>
        log.warning( "Unexpected case :" + other.getClass )
}
```

Comment: Why are you using TCP explicitly?  If all you want is a remote system then you just need akka-remoting and do not need to worry about the low level TCP stuff.  You should use TCP when you want to do lower level stuff like writing your own TCP server with some custom protocol.  Inter JVM communication between actors can be done completely with akka-remoting with no need for things like using a `Write` and an `Ack`.

Comment: The idea was to have a tcp server which contacted the remote. I was hoping i could just forward the message and that the remote could write back to the client connected to the tcp server, but i guess i cant do that? Do i need to 'ask' the backend from my tcp server instead of forwarding?

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea.  Handle the TCP related stuff in the TCP server.  Build up the incoming byte data until you hit a logical message boundary and then ask that message to the remote system.  Get a response from the remote system (again, as a case class message) and then write that back to the TCP actor as byte data.

Comment: I did what you suggested and it works fine. I'm using await though, which is a bad idea within an actor right? I should probably find a way to use pipeTo intsead. Thanks for the help!